# Trying to make table with on column align to left and another to right (+command call issue)

Tags: tables, alignment

I'm a beginner in Latex. I'm trying to create a table with one column aligned to the left and the other to the right.

Here is what I tried so far.

```
\newcommand{\cellright}[1]{\begin{flushright} #1 \end{flushright}}

\begin{flushleft} \Large
    \begin{tabular}{ c c }  
        \emph{text1} & \cellright{text2}\\ 
        \emph{text3} & \cellright{text4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
```

One problem is that when I call my 'cellright' function, I get  !

> LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

As far as I understood, /item is for some type of list and I'm not dealing with a list here.

Second problem is that `flushleft` doesn't seem to apply to the table. The original example read `\begin{center}` but text seems to be always centered in the table anyway.

Comment: You should probably read very basic documentation on `tabular` and tell if the texts need to have automatic line wrapping. You'll probably have to change the `c`s in the `tabular` preamble.

Comment: remove `\cellright` and change `c c ` to `l r`  to get  left aligned and right aligned columns

Comment: the flushleft is applied to the table _as a whole_ putting it at the left of the page, it doesn't affect the  entries of the table (which you have specified with centred columns)

Comment: Thanks all, you're right. I had started with YouTube tutorial but I realise now they were just givin code lines and explaining "what" they do but so much explain "why".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ >{\itshape}l r }
    1   &   text2\\
    3   &   text4
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As @frougon says in his comment, you really need to read some introductory text about table settings, for example [wiki: tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

Comment: Thank you, went for a slightly different version because I'll need to take some time at another moment to check what \itshape does.

Comment: @TTT, `\itshape` make text in the first column *italic*. With it is not need anymore to write in each column cells `\emph{...}`. For add this aption to column specifier you need to load `array` packages. All this is described in given link.